# After signing app for Play Store, should I keep the debug.keystore file for future updates?

Tags: android

I used Export Wizard to create and sign a certificate for google play.
I read somewhere that I have to keep the key? What do they mean by "the key"?
The keystore? The password and alias?
Should I keep the debug.keystore file or should I only remember the key alias/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I keep the debug.keystore file or should I only remember the
>   key alias/password?

Did you signed your application with `debug.keystore`? If yes then you should not do this. You no need to store (remember) debug.keystore.

From [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) :
*When you are ready to release your application for end-users, you must sign it with a suitable private key. You cannot publish an application that is signed with the debug key generated by the SDK tools*

***BUT yes, you need to keep the keystore created by yourself to sign your application which is on PlayStore.***

Comment: I used the Export Wizard. I dont know what file it has created and where does it store it

Comment: When you use export wizard, it says to create a new keystore file if not created (or choose already created keystore). Eclipse remembers the last used keystore. So try to export your application again. You can see the location of your keystore into Location value.

Comment: so If I want to use another computer, I should copy that file there?

Comment: Yes. And you need to secure this keystore file. This is going to be used for your future releases of same application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must keep the keystore, you used to sign your app, that was published to Google Play. It's must-have, when want to update your app. If you won't have it, you won't be able to sign your app with the same keystore, so you won't be able to upload updated version to Google Play store. Also, remember the passwords too. **TIP:** keep it in a few folders copied, have some backups, so you won't accidentally loose it.

Answer (score 1):

keep both:
debug.keystore, this one can be generated again and should not be a problem if you lose it.
keep you android.keystore, the one you used to sign your app. Without it you could not update your app and you'll have to sign with a new one and then create a new app on the playstore